# My footer works in Chrome and Firefox, but not Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, footer, compatibility, ie-compatibility-mode

I made a footer That looks great with Chrome and Firefox and stays at the bottom of the page where it belongs.  However, it does not work with Internet Explorer.  I tried this with Internet Explorer 10.  How can I fix this?

I have most of my page in a wrapper and in order for the footer to work, it is outside of the wrapper.

First, I should mention that after looking at the code, I realized that my float doesn't leave space at the bottom in Internet Explorer.  Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="mainfloat">
  <div class="text_body">
    <p>Text goes here.</p> 
  </div><!--text body-->
</div><!--mainfloat-->
```

This is the CSS for the mainfloat:

```
#mainfloat{
    float: left;
    position: relative; /*also important to add*/
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    min-height: 550px;
    min-width: 650px; /*this was commented out earlier*/
    max-width: 900px;
    /*width: 100%;*/ /*This is what was causing my footer to go berserk!*/
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 17%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    /*margin-bottom: 30%;*/ /*Separate the main float from the footer. Experiment*/
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom: 220px; /*makes space between float and footer*/
}
```

Here is the HTML of the footer (links have been replaced with "`#`" for the purpose of showing the code):

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_wrapper"> 
        <div class="footer_font_float_left">Quick links:</div>
        <div class="column">
          <strong>#:</strong><br />
          <a href="#">#</a><br />
          <a href="#">#</a><br />
          <a href="#">#</a><br />
          <a href="#">#</a>
       </div>
      <div class="column">
         <strong>#</strong><br />
         <a href="#">#</a><br />
         <a href="#">#</a><br />
      </div>
     <div class="column">
         <strong>Web #</strong><br />
         <a href="#">#</a><br />
     </div>
     <div class="footer_font_float_bottom">Interested? <a href="#">Contact me!</a>
     </div>
  </div><!--footer_wrapper-->     
</div><!--footer-->
```

This is the CSS:

```
#footer{
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.footer_font_float_bottom > a:link{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 11pt
}

.footer_font_float_bottom > a:visited{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 11pt
}

.column{
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 0 0 50px; /*top, right, bottom, left TRBL*/ 
}

.column > a:link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

.column > a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

.footer_font_float_bottom{
  bottom: 0;    
  margin-top: 120px;
}


#footer_wrapper{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.blank_div{
    /*margin-bottom: 30%;*/
}
```

I also included some CSS for the HTML, wrapper and body tags that help the footer:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
```

Is there a way I can just put in a code to fix its compatibility?  Is it the main float that is causing the problem?

Any help will be gratefully appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what _"However, it does not work with Internet Explorer."_ means? I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75s9108r/) with the code provided and it seems to look the same in IE 10 and Chrome.

Comment: First, I thank you for your reply.  Second, what happened is my footer won't stay at the bottom for Internet Explorer.  It worked in Chrome, but not Internet Explorer.  Lastly, I should mention that I think it might be my main float.  I edited my post and added info on my main float which is not making a margin towards the bottom of the page.  I think that is causing my footer to be bumped in the middle.

Comment: First off, give caniuse.com a look in the future to check compatibility.
"filter" doesn't seem to be compatible with any version of IE, but that doesn't appear to have anything to do with your footer.

Otherwise, same as @zgood, I can't see any difference in his fiddle from IE to chrome.

Comment: The filter is only for the transparency of the background.  It does not impact the bottom margin of the float which is what is causing the problem of my footer.  Because it is not making a margin at the bottom, the footer is in the middle of the page.

Comment: You never clear the float.